# Is there a specific session for these type of connections PHP

Tags: php

I need a session object for these type of connections mine seems not to be working with my current connection, is there a specific one of will it work with my connection. Here is the code:

Connection:

```
$conn = mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);

if (!$conn)
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db(db_name, $conn);
```

Here is my current session object but it does not seem to work with this type of connection. Here is the code:

Session:

```
session_start();

//Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']) && is_object($_SESSION['userSession']))
{
    $loggedInUser = $_SESSION['userSession'];
}
```

When I try to log in as $loggedInUser = $_SESSION['userSession']; the session does not start.
Is there another session that needs to be build or why is this session not working with my current connection?

Comment: I don't see any connection between the code above (which is about establishing a database connection) and the code below (which is about sessions). What do you mean by "seems not to work", what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you receiving a `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_name`? If so, I recommending reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php).

Comment: When I try to log in as $loggedInUser = $_SESSION['userSession']; the session does not start

Comment: What are you putting into `$_SESSION['userSession']`?

Comment: So where are you Setting this `SESSION` ? DO you have any output before `session_start()`? Even outside PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Storing an object in `$_SESSION` causes it to be serialised and deserialised. For regular objects this works provided the class definition is included before the object is deserialised.

However, `mysql` maintains the state of the database connection, which won't survive the process. Each new page requires a new connection to be built, so you can't store a `mysql` connection in `$_SESSION`.

Your solution is to store the database connection parameters and recreate the connection at the top of every page.

Comment: doesn't look like what he is doing to me

Comment: I've no clear idea **what** he's doing. This is my best guess.

Comment: so you answer rather than vote to close as unclear, each to his own :-)